# How to debug canvas in browser?

Tags: debugging, html5-canvas

How to debug canvas?

It's loading bunch of rotating images in canvas. I want to check what images they are. But firebug shows nothing but the canvas tag.

Is there any way to find out what these canvas pre-loaded images are so I can download them?

Comment: Sir, step out of the car and put your hands in the air!  As the answerers explain, you can examine the javascript files to see the source url of the images, but please be sure you aren't violating someone's digital rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can check the new [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) feature of 3D view of the page (canvas, div, ...).
2. You can place `debugger;` in your javascript code, so the debugger will automatically stop there.

Comment: Very cool.Though it is not firebug feature. It's in the default inspector feature of Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0):

Images drawn to canvas elements are loaded by javascript e.g.

```
var img = new Image();
image.onload = function(){ draw on canvas };
img.src = "image url";
```

You could try searching the JS source for .jpg or .png references, etc.